# How to config Yii framework to connect MySQL over SSH?

Tags: mysql, yii

I have local MySql server and want Yii to connect to it over SSH. I have try to config config/main.php but failed. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to forward port 3306 from the remote server to your local machine and then set Yii to connect to the forwarded port on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by hd1: This is something you need to do outside of PHP. 
The best way is to create an SSH tunnel so that you have a port on the local server to talk to, that connects to your actual database server. There was a discussion on the Yii forum about exactly this, you can find it [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/30678-mysql-through-ssh-tunnel/)

You might want to take a look at AutoSSH as well.